# AWS Ubuntu SSH suddenly disconnects and can't reconnect

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I created a new micro instance of Ubuntu Server 20.04 and connected with putty successfully. I did some work on the server, setting up nginx and other things. Out of the blue, my connection got disconnected and then when I try to reconnect using putty, I get a connection timeout. I spent a while trying to figure out what was wrong and gave up, so I created a new instance and did some work, and after about an hour, the same thing happened, disconnected and can't reconnect with a timeout error. What could cause this? How do I even troubleshoot?

Comment: Can you connect using Web ssh client (EC2 Instance Connect)?

Comment: No, when I try to connect through the AWS console, I get: There was a problem connecting to your instance
We were unable to connect to your instance. Make sure that your instance’s network settings are configured correctly for EC2 Instance Connect.

Comment: Your instance may have run out of disc or memory. What instance type do you use?

Comment: t2.micro.. I only installed and configured nginx and didn't do much else. also when I reboot the server, I still can't connect. do you think it can be a memory or disc space problem?

Comment: Nah, its your not running anything there, so there is no reason for ram or disc space to run out. Does this also happen with new instances, which you are not modifying at all? In other words, do you loose access only after your modifications, or its a general problem?

Comment: I have a Ubunto 18.x version that has been running for years without issues and was trying to set up a 20.04 server and migrate some websites over and this happened to me twice today. all I was doing was configuring nginx so it either had something to do with that, or something with the micro instance, or some other issue.

Answer (score 2):

So in the instructions for configuring NGINX on Ubuntu it gives instructions for configuring UFW, and says I needed to allow HTTP and HTTPS but made no mention of SSH, so I allowed SSH "ufw allow ssh" and then set ENABLED=yes in /etc/ufw/ufw.conf, and so far so good.

Comment: mark this as an accepted answer, i was doing the same thing and was creating many servers to find out the issue, the command sudo enable ufw stops all SSH connections, but adding 'ufw allow ssh' ensured that the SSH connection exists